# How to navigate current google chrome or firefox or edge tab with different URL

Tags: c#, wpf, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

Hello StackOverflow,

I have two associate application. one is in web platform (ASP.NET) and another is a windows application (WPF). the user can open windows application from web application by custom web protocol but when they want to go to the web application from windows application we are using below code for Internet Explorer to navigate already open web page of our web application with different query string or different URL from the windows application.

> Interop.SHDocVw.dll

```
ShellWindows iExplorerInstances = new ShellWindows();
foreach (InternetExplorer iExplorer in iExplorerInstances)
{
    if (iExplorer.LocationName.Contains("File Info")
        && iExplorer.LocationURL.StartsWith("http://www.example.com"))
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(iExplorer.LocationURL);
        string NewUrl = string.Format(@"{0}://{1}//FileInfo.aspx?FileID={2}", uri.Scheme, uri.Authority, FileID);
        iExplorer.Navigate(NewUrl);
        IsPageFound = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

My Question is how to do the same things in Google Chrome, Firefox and Edge browser.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just Process.Start(uri)?

Comment: @AntonShakalo I don't want to open URL in new tab. I just want to reload existing tab with different URL.

Comment: Ok, answer is simple: you can't

Comment: Hard answer: possible you can if you manage to create browser extension that would be able to communicate with your app but I'm not sure it is possible